# ipv6 i can't connect from the outside

Tags: unix, networking, ipv6, freebsd, netbsd

I'm testing IPv6 networking (using FreeBSSD .0, VMWare, NAT), but I can't connect from outside (localhost) via an IPv6 address(using IPv4, it works fine). How can I set up the network properly?

```
[root@ /home/osmund]# cat /etc/rc.conf
hostname=""
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
ifconfig_em1_ipv6="inet6 2001:db8:1::1 prefixlen 64"
#ipv6_enable="YES"
ipv6_network_interface="em1"
ifconfig_le0="DHCP"
sshd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="AUTO"
[root@ /home/osmund]# ifconfig
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 00:0c:29:8f:45:74
    inet6 2001:db8:1::1 prefixlen 64
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe8f:4574%em1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
    inet 192.168.124.133 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.124.255
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
plip0: flags=8810<POINTOPOINT,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
[root@ /home/osmund]# ping6 2001:db8:1::1
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2001:db8:1::1 --> 2001:db8:1::1
16 bytes from 2001:db8:1::1, icmp_seq=0 hlim=64 time=0.529 ms
16 bytes from 2001:db8:1::1, icmp_seq=1 hlim=64 time=0.133 ms
^C
--- 2001:db8:1::1 ping6 statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 0.133/0.331/0.529/0.198 ms

[root@ /home/osmund]#
```

Comment: Just a heads up, but 2001:db8 in IPv6 is used for documentation only and should not be used in production. If you are testing IPv6 you will want to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address (ULA) addresses instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use bridged network instead?